# Should I have client and contractor billable items in the same table or separate?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to store client and contractor billable items into my DB.  It does not appear that I would be doing any queries to search both client and contractor billable items in a single query, or used in an interchangeable way where inheritance would help.  However, because they would share many columns, it makes me feel like I should use single table inheritance and have them both in the same table.  I'm pretty sure I should just keep them separate, but the fact that the objects are so similar makes me unsure, especially if things change in the future and they are looked at in an interchangeable way.

Comment: You can use a single table given your input.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably Clients and Contractors are held in separate tables? Assuming that that is so, then I'd go with separate tables. If at some time you need to query both at once, then given their similarity it should be simple enough to create a view over both tables, but remember [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Ain%27t_Gonna_Need_It)!

Cheers -